# Is there any other solution for my question?

Tags: sql-server

for an given input i need to get desired output

**Input**

```
table1                                   
+----------------------+
id      |    coursename   
+-----------------------+      
1            SQL
2            Artificial Intelligence
3            Machine Learning

table2

+---------------------------+
id       |    teachername
+----------------------------+
1             shreya
1             ramya
2             darshan
2             ravi

table3

+----------------------------+
id        |   studentname
+-----------------------------+
1               raj
1              mani
1              chandru
2              prem
```

**Output**

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
id        | coursename            |    teachername  | studentname
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1            SQL                        shreya         raj
1            SQL                        ramya          mani
1            SQL                        null           chandru
2          artificial intelligence       darshan       prem
2          artificial intelligence        ravi          null
3          machine learning               null         null
```

I got solution in one way

```
SELECT c.id,
       c.coursename,
       t.teachername,
       s.studentname
FROM  (SELECT id,
              teachername,
              row_number()
                OVER(
                  partition BY id
                  ORDER BY id) AS teach
       FROM   table2)AS t
      FULL JOIN(SELECT id,
                       studentname,
                       row_number()
                         OVER(
                           partition BY id
                           ORDER BY id) AS stud
                FROM   table3) AS s
             ON( t.teach = s.stud
                 AND t.id = s.id )
      RIGHT JOIN (SELECT id,
                         coursename
                  FROM   table1) AS c
              ON( c.id = s.id
                   OR c.id = t.id )
```

Comment: There are countless ways to express any SQL query, but I can't think of any offhand that would be much better than yours.

Comment: Ya but also I wanted to know what are the ways to get result

Comment: Posting a broken query without explanation will not help us help you.  What do you want to do???

Answer (score 0):

You want `LEFT JOIN` with `FULL OUTER JOIN` :

```
WITH cte AS (
     SELECT t1.id, t1.coursename, t2.teachername,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id ORDER BY(SELECT 1)) AS RN
     FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
          table2 t2
          ON t2.id = t1.id

), cte1 AS (
     SELECT t1.id, t1.coursename, t3.studentname,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id ORDER BY(SELECT 1)) AS RN
     FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
          table3 t3
          ON t3.id = t1.id
)

SELECT ISNULL(c.id, c1.id) AS id, ISNULL(c.coursename, c1.coursename) AS coursename, c.teachername, c1.studentname
FROM cte c full outer join
     cte1 c1 
     ON c1.id = c.id and c1.RN = c.RN;
```

Comment: i have given picture description .. please check that

Comment: It appears OP requires that row numbers match.  For example, the third AI student should be matched to the third AI teacher.

Comment: Is there any other ways to get the required output?

Comment: @MartinSmith. . . Yes that really missed.

Comment: @balajiDev. . . You need `FULL OUTER JOIN` with `CTE`c.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have teacher id in the student table and teacher id in the teacher table:

```
DECLARE @course TABLE
(
    Id int,
    CourseName varchar(100)
)

DECLARE @teacher TABLE
(
    CId int,
    TId int,
    TeacherName varchar(100)
)

DECLARE @student TABLE
(
    Id int,
    TId int,
    StudentName varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @course VALUES(1,'SQL')
INSERT INTO @course VALUES(2,'AI')
INSERT INTO @course VALUES(3,'ML')

INSERT INTO @teacher VALUES(1, 1,'shreya')
INSERT INTO @teacher VALUES(1, 2, 'ramya')
INSERT INTO @teacher VALUES(2, 3, 'darshan')
INSERT INTO @teacher VALUES(2, 4, 'ravi')

INSERT INTO @student VALUES(1,1,'raj')
INSERT INTO @student VALUES(1,1,'mani')
INSERT INTO @student VALUES(1,2,'chandra')
INSERT INTO @student VALUES(2,3,'prem')


SELECT c.Id, c.CourseName, t.TeacherName, s.StudentName 
FROM @course c  
    LEFT JOIN @teacher t ON c.Id = t.CId 
    LEFT JOIN @student s ON c.Id = s.Id AND t.TId = s.TId
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution..but I want output without  breaking  table

Comment: there is no relation between teacher and student, so it will be duplicate rows! or you can contact teacher name by comma separated values.